# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have table with columns as `id`,`title`,`relation_key`.  I wanted to get `count(*)` as well as title for corresponding`relation_key` column.

My table contains the following data:

```
id           title          relation_key
55           title1111         10
56           title2222         10
57           MytitleVVV        20
58           MytitlleXXX       20
```

I tried:

```
select title,count(*)  from table  where relation_key=10 group by title
```

But its returning 1 row only. I want both records of title for `relation_key=10`

Comment: it is working fine for me http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/934d7/3

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
select title, count(*) over (partition by relation_key)
from table 
where relation_key = 10
```

The result of this would yield:

```
title     | count
----------+------
title1111 | 2
title2222 | 2
```

Note that you cannot select fields that are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause in Oracle (as in most other databases).

As a general rule of thumb, you should avoid grouping if you don't really want to group data, but just use [aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm) such as `count(*)`. Most of Oracle's aggregate functions can be transformed into [window functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) by adding an `over()` clause, removing the need for a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an Error then Please try with following.

```
select title,count(*)  from table  where relation_key=10 group by title,relation_key
```

Comment: In this case, `count(*)` would yield `1` for every record. I'm not sure if this is what the OP intends as they seem to want to count by `relation_key` only...